# Is it correct for me to understand why air moves along a curved surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, flow

[image: Fig. 1]

As shown in Fig. 1, water flows horizontally from A-A section, and it flows along the surface under the action of gravity. As long as the velocity is not high enough, the water will not leave the surface.

[image: Fig. 2]

As shown in Fig. 2, air flows horizontally from the A-A section, and the air moves along the curved surface. Is this also the result of gravity?
 
Some people think that this is not the result of gravity, because the gravity of air is counteracted by buoyancy. In my opinion, this explanation is incorrect. The gravity of air will not be counteracted. If the gravity of air will be counteracted by buoyancy, then how can there be atmospheric pressure?

[image: Fig. 3]

As shown in Fig. 3, IJ is the ground, and ADHG is the atmospheric column per unit area of the ground. This atmospheric column has three parts: ADCB, BCFE and EFHG. Obviously, although the cube BCFE is subject to buoyancy. But the pressure on the ground HG is equal to the sum of the weight of the three parts. All the weight of the atmosphere is transmitted to the ground.

Others explained that it was because of the viscosity. I think this explanation is also wrong.

I think the reason is gravity. Because gravity oppresses air, it cannot leave the surface. Unless the velocity of the air is large enough, gravity cannot keep the air on the surface. Gravity oppresses the moving air, which provides the centripetal force for the moving air and makes the air move along the curved surface. It is also because part of gravity is used to provide centripetal force that the air pressure on the surface decreases and negative pressure (below atmospheric pressure) is generated on the surface. The negative pressure on the top of the wing is also the reason. So the top of the wing generates lift.

[image: Fig. 4]

As shown in Fig. 4, it has been suggested that even if the curved surface is upward, the air flow will move along the curved surface, which is contrary to the direction of gravity, so gravity is not the cause. I don't think the explanation that gravity is not the cause is correct.

[image: Fig. 5]

As shown in Fig. 5, this is a flat plate placed horizontally in the atmosphere. As we all know, both the upper surface of the flat plate and the lower surface of the flat plate are atmospheric pressure. It's not because the lower surface is downward, so it's not atmospheric pressure. And how does atmospheric pressure come about? Gravity is the cause of atmospheric pressure.

As shown in Fig. 1, because of the weight of the atmosphere, the reason why water moves along the surface consists of two factors, one is the weight of water, the other is the weight of the atmosphere. As shown in Fig. 2, the motion of airflow along the surface is also caused by two factors, one is the weight of air flow, the other is the weight of the atmosphere. In Fig. 4, although the surface is curved upward and the gravity of the airflow is downward, the airflow will also move along the "upward" surface due to the weight of the atmosphere.

---

Without gravity, there would be no atmospheric pressure, so atmospheric pressure is actually the spokesman of atmospheric gravity. When you apply atmospheric pressure to lift, you are applying gravity.

---

**Because the surface is curved, the air flow tends to leave the surface along the normal direction. On the side near the surface, the air pressure decreases. Because the air pressure far from the surface does not decrease, the pressure difference makes the air flow move along the surface.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95281/discussion-on-question-by-enbin-zheng-is-it-correct-for-me-to-understand-why-air).

Answer (score 2):

Gravity will only cause the air at any specific density to want to stay at the elevation where air is at that density, due to buoyancy.

This causes air to follow the curved surface *of Earth*; the object that is exerting the force of gravity on it.  Gravity is not sufficient to make it follow *any* curved surface, as you seem to be suggesting.

What makes it follow *any* curved surface to some extent will be the effects of viscosity, as you claim should not be the case.  Due to the [no-slip condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-slip_condition), there will be no movement between the gas and the solid surface.  This air stationary with the surface also slows down the air near to it, due to the nature of viscosity, leading to a layer of air that is directly affected by the surface in contact with it.  This is known as a boundary layer, and would occur even if the curve was pointed upwards, causing the motion of the flow to go *against* gravity; which should be sufficient to show that gravity cannot fully explain this.

There can also be the [Coandă effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) at play, when we have a forced stream of air with stationary air surrounding it.  In that case, even more air is brought into the system due to pressure differences and [entrainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrainment_(hydrodynamics)), along with viscosity.  If the Coandă effect is in play (which it seems to be from your diagrams, assuming the white areas contain air that was not given a starting velocity), then the air can actually follow quite a large amount of curvature depending on the flow velocities and surfaces involved.  Viscosity allows it to follow the surface somewhat; but the Coandă effect greatly amplifies the capability.

With the Coandă effect the situation below also naturally occurs, which clearly disproves the notion that gravity is the cause:

[image: Opposing gravity]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95291/discussion-on-answer-by-jmac-is-it-correct-for-me-to-understand-why-air-moves-al).